# JTable header background color

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

I'm trying to put background color on the JTable header but it seems that it doesnt change the header's color this is my code for my JTable.. what am I doing wrong?

```
Color headerColor = new Color(25, 78, 132);
        itemTable = new JTable(){

        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {                
            return false;               
        };
        Color rowColor1 = new Color(99, 154, 206);
        Color rowColor2 = new Color(148, 186, 231);
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
            Component stamp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            if (row % 2 == 0)
                stamp.setBackground(rowColor1);
            else
                stamp.setBackground(rowColor2);
            return stamp;
        }
        };
        JTableHeader Header =  itemTable.getTableHeader();
        Header.setBackground(headerColor);
        Header.setReorderingAllowed(false);
        itemTable.setFont(fpanelItemTable);
        itemTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION); 
        //itemTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        //itemTable.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        itemTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Comment: note prepareRenderer isnt proper for this job

Comment: where should I put it? I want my header and rows to have color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where should I put it? I want my header and rows to have color

- for example, one of three possible ways

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SelectedTableHeader {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Demo");
    private JTableHeader header;
    private Object selectedColumn = null;
    private String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Float", "Double", "Locale & Double", "Boolean"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"aaa", new Integer(12), new Float(12.15), new Double(100.05), new Double(12.05), true},
        {"bbb", new Integer(5), new Float(7.154), new Double(6.1555), new Double(417.55), false},
        {"CCC", new Integer(92), new Float(0.1135), new Double(3.1455), new Double(11.05), true},
        {"ddd", new Integer(12), new Float(31.15), new Double(10.05), new Double(23.05), true},
        {"eee", new Integer(5), new Float(5.154), new Double(16.1555), new Double(17.55), false},
        {"fff", new Integer(92), new Float(4.1135), new Double(31.1455), new Double(3.05), true}};
    private TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };
    private JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
                int firstRow = 0;
                int secondRow = 0;
                int lastRow = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                if (row == lastRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                } else if (row == firstRow) {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                } else {
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(table.getBackground());
                }
                return c;
            }
        };

    public SelectedTableHeader() {
        header = table.getTableHeader();
        header.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JTableHeader h = (JTableHeader) e.getSource();
                int i = h.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                Object o = h.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getHeaderValue();
                if (i < 0) {
                    selectedColumn = null;
                    return;
                }
                selectedColumn = o;
                h.requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
        final TableCellRenderer hr = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        header.setDefaultRenderer(new TableCellRenderer() {
            private JLabel lbl;
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, 
                    int row, int column) {
                if (selectedColumn == value) {
                    lbl = (JLabel) hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
                            true, true, row, column);
                    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1)));
                    lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
                    lbl.setBackground(lbl.getBackground());
                } else {
                    lbl = (JLabel) hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, 
                            false, false, row, column);
                    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                            lbl.getBorder(), 
                            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1)));
                    lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                    lbl.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                }
                if (column == 0) {
                    lbl.setForeground(Color.red);
                } else {
                    lbl.setForeground(header.getForeground());
                }
                /*return (value == selectedColumn) ? hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                 table, value, true, true, row, column) : hr.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                 table, value, false, false, row, column);*/
                return lbl;
            }
        });
        table.setRowHeight(20);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SelectedTableHeader sTH = new SelectedTableHeader();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. so I should seperate the cell and header renderer am I right? and I have one more question why is the double head arrow is not visible when there I put color on the header? how can I make it visible again?

Comment: `cell and header renderer am I right?` ---> yes, `why is the double head arrow is not visible when there I put color on the header?` ---> please whats??? no idea without details...., are you meaning sorting icons or ???

Comment: yes. when the header has no color the sorting icon or the double head arrow is visible then when the header has color the icon does not appear.. why?