# Dynamically adding JTable header color/text

Tags: java, jtable

My project involves a JTable and GUI. The user populates the JTable by adding "transactions" (represented as a row) and can then copy or delete these "transactions" at will.

I have decided that I want to add some more color to the table. In particular I would like to have every other header and column have a black background with white text so that it is easy to view.

I have been able to write the code to accomplish with the columns. I have also been able to change the color of ALL column headers. The problem that I seem to be having is changing individual column headers dynamically (like I do the columns). I have referred to the question here: [JTable header background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207756/jtable-header-background-color) but am very confused by it.. The solution posted is quite complicated and I am having trouble translating it to my individual code. Here is what I have so far:

```
tbl = new JTable();

        String header[] = new String[]{

                "Notification Reference Number", "Amount","Credit/Debit Indicator","Initiating Party Id",
                "Initiating Party Scheme Name", "Debtor Name","Debtor Zip Code","Debtor Town",
                "Debtor Country Sub-Division","Debtor Address","Debtor Agent Clearing System Id","Debtor Agent Name",
                "Creditor Agent Clearing System Id",
                "Creditor Agent Name",
                "Return/Reject Code","Return/Reject Additional Info",
                "Payment Instrument","Type of Payment","Pass-Thru Data","Clearing Account","Transaction Type",
                "Return Occurence","Retired Indicator","Representment Method",
                "Check-Split Indicator","Check Split Amount","Corporate Check Indicator","Source Batch Identifier"

        };

        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(header);

        tbl.setModel(dtm);

        tbl.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        scroll.getViewport().setBackground(Color.gray);

        boolean flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < header.length; i++){



            tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(200);

            if(flag==false){
                TableColumn tm = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

                tm.setCellRenderer(new ColorColumnRenderer(Color.black,Color.white));
                flag=true;

            }else if(flag==true){
                TableColumn tm = tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                tm.setCellRenderer(new ColorColumnRenderer(Color.white, Color.black));
                flag=false;

            }

        }
```

As you can see I use the "flag" Boolean to ensure that every other column is changed. Here is the code for changing the columns:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}

class ColorColumnRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{

    Color bkgndColor, fgndColor;

    public ColorColumnRenderer(Color bkgnd, Color foregnd){
        super();
        bkgndColor = bkgnd;
        fgndColor = foregnd;

    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
    (JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) 
    {

        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent
                (table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);


        cell.setBackground(bkgndColor);
        cell.setForeground(fgndColor);

        return cell;


    }
}
```

During experimenting I was able to set all headers with this:

```
tbl.getTableHeader().setOpaque(false);
            tbl.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.black);
            tbl.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.white);
```

I have tried numerous methods of coding a specific header but all are unsuccessful. I'm sure the solution is simple I just can't figure it out.

I should note that I apologize for not posting a full code example. This code is actually quite complex so I was hoping someone might be able to easily identify what I need to do before I have to create new JTable and try to isolate this example - Although I will do this if necessary.